# Bluez and dbus - set track playback position / jump to position

Tags: bluetooth, position, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to build a small-as-possible bluetooth receiver using a raspberry pi zero w with raspian, see:

- https://github.com/sandreas/raspberry-bluetooth-receiver or
- https://github.com/BaReinhard/Super-Simple-Raspberry-Pi-Audio-Receiver-Install

for details...

Bluetooth audio playback with my iPod Nano is already working as expected and i can control the playback (Play, Pause, Stop, FastForward, Rewind) via dbus commands.

**Now i am trying to find a way to set the playback position**, e.g. jump from 3:30 to 3:00 (30 second rewind).

After reading the bluez media-api:

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/media-api.txt

i did not find any possibility to jump to a specific playback position, since Position is a **READONLY** property:

```
uint32 Position [readonly]
        Playback position in milliseconds. Changing the
        position may generate additional events that will be
        sent to the remote device. When position is 0 it means
        the track is starting and when it's greater than or
        equal to track's duration the track has ended. Note
        that even if duration is not available in metadata it's
        possible to signal its end by setting position to the
        maximum uint32 value.
```

As a workaround i could do a rewind on 3:30, repeatedly read the position and set status to play again if it is lower than equal 3:00, but this takes to long if i would like to go from 3:30 to 1:30.

My Questions:

- Is a "jump to position" even possible or specified via dbus / bluez?
- If its not possible via dbus, is there another tool or script that works with raspian?

Comment: Any results? I'm having the same problem. Please share with us

Comment: Nope, i did not find any further information so far.

Comment: I found this command; `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_$btadr/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.FastForward` (run `bluetoothctl devices paired` to get the address. the problem for me was that FastForward was seeking, so I swapped it for 'Next'